Как отправлять сообщения в определенное время? Aiogram3
Пишу бота для телеграмма на python с использованием библиотеки aiogram3. У меня есть база данных sqlite3 в которой храниться время и id пользоваться и мне нужно чтоб каждый день бот отправлял людям информацию по времени которое указано в этой базе данных. Может быть можно использовать какую то доп. библиотеку для отправки?

Через цикл проверяете какое сейчас время, если оно совпадает с теми значениями, которые были у вас в базе данных, то отправляете сообщение через bot.send_message по id.
